# Is it possible to make quick ribbon buttons affected by modifier+click (Office-2016)?

Tags: excel, vba

I've only spent a little bit of time searching to see if this is possible.  This is only to determine if possible; I will follow-up with a separate code related question if I can get that far.

I use lots of quick-ribbon buttons to call macros, but want to avoid having 30 buttons up there (the white-wash from 2016 office is really screwing with me).  I would like to use one button to perform different functions if I use a different modifier, e.g.:

```
A) Click = Macro A
B) Shift+click = Macro B
C) Ctrl+click = Macro C
D) Alt+click = Macro D
```

Is this possible?  If so, any tips for specific search terms, or more relevant terms than *quick ribbon macro select with modifiers* which gave me nothing.

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option for what you want to do with the ribbon. You would have to make your own form and trap the mouse events.